# Using one view that will handle the displaying the photos for each photo gallery in MVC depending on the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, photo-gallery

I am trying to create a photo gallery using mvc and want to know if I can avoid creating several individual views for each gallery.

Here is how I plan on it being structured:

**/Media/Photos**
This page will list one cover picture for each gallery with the gallery's title.
i.e
Gallery 1
Gallery 2

Is there a way to use one individual view and from /Media/Photos when they click an Image Link it will navigate them to Media/Photos/GalleryTitle

Based on the title I will show the correct images.

**/Media/Photos/Gallery1**
This page will display all individual photos in gallery 1
**/Media/Photos/Gallery2**
This page will display all individual photos in gallery 2

and so on

If I can't do this I will have to create a view for every single gallery.

One thing to note is that I will not be pulling anything from the database. It will all be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be easily possible, it is just a parameter into the individual controller method.

Example

```
public ActionResult GalleryDisplay(int id)
{
    //Grab the items and populate a view model
    return View(yourVmHere);
}
```

Assuming a standard route, you could do this from the Photos controller with a URL structure like

```
/Photos/GalleryDisplay/1
```

If you wanted to put text into the route, just add a variation into the route path to handle the string after.

Comment: So your saying in my controller I would set all of the image src paths into a list and then send them to the view to be looped through using razor? So my controller method would have a large case statement in it I am assuming.

Comment: @WilliamVenice, You don't need a case statement. This is passing an ID value identifying the gallery. You just need to get a collection of images where the `Gallery == ID` and loop through them in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The reason I am saying I will need a case statement is because everything is static. For example I am going to create a Model called Photo that has two properties Title, ImageUrl. Then IF ID=1 create a new List<Photo>() and add everything that is in Gallery1 to it, then send to View. Does this make sense since I don't have a repository or anything to pull from based on ID? Could you tell me how I would do it by gallery title which is text rather than ID? I'm not sure what he means by add a variation to the route path to handle the string after.

Comment: So how are you identifying which images belong to which Gallery? I still don't understand why you think you need a case statement? And instead of `int id` it could be `string gallery` and get the images where `Gallery == gallery`

Comment: I think I just figured out a way to do it. Create a model Photo (Id, Title, ImageSrc). Then in my controller create a private property of type List<Photo> called GalleryImages and add every single image to this list. Then I can simple use linq to do the where clause you are talking about. Does this make sense?

Comment: You haven't given us any information about how your store your images and how you categorize them by Gallery so impossible to tell (why would you add every image to the list instead of just adding the relevant images (i.e. for the Gallery)

Comment: Thats what I was trying to say. I do not have my image paths stored in a database or any kind of repository. I have a bunch of images organized in my Content folder and I simply want to display them based on the gallery title in the url. I will just create an object list of type Photo to act as my repository for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91155/discussion-between-william-venice-and-stephen-muecke).